# Java code - number of files in a JAR

Tags: java, jar, size

I want to find the number of files the JAR contains.  Is there a way to do it without looping through like this:

```
while (enumEntries.hasMoreElements()) {
    enumEntries.nextElement();
    count++;
}
```

I want to have the number of files *before* I loop through the entries.  It seems not elegant to loop through them twice.

Comment: what is the purpose of the assignation to `JarEntry file`?

Comment: There isn't one really.  Edited the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [size()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#size--) to count the number of entries that's what your loop return.

Uses

```
JarFile f = new JarFile(new File("path.jar"));
System.out.println(f.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

JAR files are basically zip files.

So you can use the jar java class to retrieve the infos from it,
like [in this post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/279471/elegant-way-to-count-the-number-of-files-in-zip-archive).

Be aware that the size() method returns the number of entries,
which can also include folders and not only files.